# SQL insert error SQL syntax ... date()

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is the error i'm receiving 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':i:s a), rec_type = '', rec_request = '1', rec_by = 'Victoria', batch_id = UC' at line 1

also i'm aware that I need to escape before inserting. I'm just testing right now.

```
$importwav="INSERT into names SET 
com_id = '".$word_id."',
rec_date = date(d-M-y),
rec_time = date(h:i:s a),
rec_type = '".$rec_type."',
rec_request = '1',
rec_by = '".$data[8]."',
batch_id = UCASE('".$batchid."')
";


    INSERT into names SET com_id = '87', rec_date = date(d-M-y), 
rec_time = date(h:i:s a), rec_type = '', rec_request = '1', 
rec_by = 'Victoria', batch_id = UCASE('Batch004AM')
```

Comment: **rec date could be of Y-m-d format**

Comment: make single `rec_date` field of `datetime` type and assign both date and time at once with `rec_date=localtime`.

Comment: don't be a fool, use proper date format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing your PHP functions and your MySQL functions.

```
$importwav="INSERT into names SET 
com_id = '".$word_id."',
rec_date = '" . date('d-M-y') . "',
rec_time = '" . date('h:i:s a') . "',
 ...
```

And your SQL syntax is FUBAR.

Comment: Hmmm...  Inacio says your SQL syntax is FUBAR and gets 3 votes.  I say your SQL syntax is improper and get a negative vote.   Oh well..

Comment: @Brian he is wrong with that remark and the rest of the answer is okay (save for not to mention lame data format). While your answer actually helps nothing and, as the op mentioned in the comment, being used literally, can't solve the problem. Because his ptoblem is different. Just write your answers on topic to get upvotes. That's damn easy.

Answer (score 0):

Improper SQL syntax.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)
```

Comment: i use to do it that way, but it gets way to confusing when inserting a lot of field entries.

Answer (score -1):

`date()` arguments need to be a string. Try surrounding your date format strings with single quotes (`'`).